# How to make an API call in struct

Tags: swift, api, struct, swiftui

So I'm trying to make a call to Google Places API to get some info on gyms near some coordinates nearby.

I'm using SwiftUI for this and this is my Struct for MapView atm.

At the moment I'm using VancouverPoints as just a test and its working; but I'd like to use my getPlaces() method to populate gymPlaces, then make the API call and get the places that way instead but I'm not sure how to proceed.

When I use my API_KEY just doing a search I get a bunch of information back which is good though :)

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: LocationViewModel
    
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 49.250944, longitude: -122.759012), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))

    // I want to use this in the future
    private var gymPoints = getPlaces()
    
    private var vancouverPoints = [
        AnnotatedItem(name: "Science park", coordinate: .init(latitude: 49.27477428248723, longitude: -123.1036925314458)),
        AnnotatedItem(name: "Stanely park", coordinate: .init(latitude: 49.30405290703585, longitude: -123.14429044749619))
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: vancouverPoints) { item in
                MapMarker(coordinate: item.coordinate, tint: .red)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

func getPlaces() -> [AnnotatedItem]{
    var longitudeX = "-122.735960"
    var latitudeY = "49.252400"
    
    var annotatedItems: [AnnotatedItem]
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(latitudeY),\(longitudeX)&radius=15000&types=gym&key=APP_KEY")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    print("Request code done")
    
    // Code to get data from API
    
    // Code to fill annotatedItems
    
    
    return annotatedItems // Currently unitiliazed.
}
```

Almost forgot
AnnotatedItem class:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

struct AnnotatedItem: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        var name: String
        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

Comment: Put the logic into `LocationViewModel` and use a `@Published` property to update the view.

Comment: @vadian Would the be the getPlaces() -> [] logic? Do you mean?

Comment: Yes, and call it in `.onAppear`

Comment: @vadian Ok I put it in there; but I don't see a .onAppear in LocationViewModel I tried ctrl F but didn't find anything

Comment: No, call `getPlaces()` in `.onAppear` in the **view** (you have to add the modifier) and pass the coordinate if needed.

Comment: Oh like back in MapView: View Struct? Would I attach that to the end var body: Some View then?

var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: vancouverPoints) { item in
                MapMarker(coordinate: item.coordinate, tint: .red)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all).onAppear(viewModel.getPlaces())
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246684/discussion-between-coding-noob-and-vadian).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example you could modify to work with Google Places:

```
struct Product: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    
    static func load() async throws -> [Product] {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string: "https://fakestoreapi.com/products")!)
        return try JSONDecoder().decode([Product].self, from: data)
    }
}

struct ProductsView: View {
    @State var products: [Product] = []
    @State var message = ""
    
    func load() async  {
        message = "Loading..."
        products = []
        do {
            products = try await Product.load()
            message = "\(products.count) products"
        }
        catch {
            message = "Failed to load"
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(message) {
                ForEach(products) { product in
                    Text(product.title)
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await load()
        }
        .refreshable {
            await load()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm trying out a networking layer solution at the moment; but if it fails I'll give this a shot! :D

Comment: I added refreshable and had to redesign it a bit because the loading message wouldn't appear when the async started, I think this is better